# For a function decorator, how can a single optional kwarg item be type-constrained, but otherwise kept generic?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a decorator that looks for an optional `kwargs` item, `foo`, with all other `*args` and `**kwargs` passed through to the decorated function.

I want the typing hints to specify which type that specific item must be, if it is present.

---

**For the following snippet, how can I create the typing partial constraint on `FnParams` such that *IFF* `foo` item is present, then its type MUST be `str` ?**

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, TypedDict, Required, NotRequired, Unpack, cast, Any

FnRet = TypeVar("FnRet")

# how can this be partially constrained to _required_ type `str`,
# if `foo` item is present?
FnParams = ParamSpec("FnParams")

FnType = Callable[FnParams, FnRet]

def decorator(fn: FnType) -> FnType:
    def wrapper(*args: FnParams.args, **kwargs: FnParams.kwargs) -> FnRet: # type: ignore[type-var]
        if "foo" in kwargs:
            assert type(kwargs["foo"]) == str
        return cast(FnRet, fn(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

## Should pass:

@decorator
def ok_1() -> int:
    return 42


class RequiredFooKwArgs(TypedDict):
    foo: Required[str]

@decorator
def ok_required_foo(*_args: Any, **kwargs: Unpack[RequiredFooKwArgs]) -> int:
    return 42

class NotRequiredFooKwArgs(TypedDict):
    foo: NotRequired[str]

@decorator
def ok_not_required_foo(*_args: Any, **kwargs: Unpack[NotRequiredFooKwArgs]) -> int:
    return 42


## The Badies:

class BadTypeRequiredFooKwArgs(TypedDict):
    foo: Required[int] # <--- this should be flagged as the wrong type

@decorator
def bad_type_required_foo(*_args: Any, **kwargs: Unpack[BadTypeRequiredFooKwArgs]) -> int:
    return 42


class BadTypeNotRequiredFooKwArgs(TypedDict):
    foo: NotRequired[int] # <--- this should be flagged as the wrong type

@decorator
def bad_type_not_required_foo(*_args: Any, **kwargs: Unpack[BadTypeNotRequiredFooKwArgs]) -> int:
    return 42
```

---

When I type check this code with `mypy` 1.5.1, I get:

```bash
mypy --enable-incomplete-feature=Unpack ~/tmp.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

What I'd like is to augment `FnParams` with a `foo` field type constraint and then have some python type-checker fail the static analysis.

Comment: This seems impossible (no constraints support for `ParamSpec` is explicitly mentioned in it's PEP). Just FYI: you [don't need](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=885179924d2a99b9465673cc7abc6c65) `type: ignore` and cast there, your `FnType` **does not** bind type variables and is simply an alias for `Callable` that still needs two args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this isn't available yet:

https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#concatenating-keyword-parameters

However, there is room for this in the future.